# Product of two distribution functions.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let F and G be two distribution functions, does the product FG still a distribution function?

Comment: Do you mean point-wise product? If so, no. Consider (1,0) and (0,1), the point-wise product is (0,0) which isn't a distribution.

Comment: I don't quite understand your example. But I mean point-wise product, basically F(x)G(x) when F(x) and G(x) are two CDFs.

Comment: I was assuming they are PDFs and not CDFs. If they are CDFs, then, two things are to be proven. First one is that the product is non-decreasing, second one is sup(FG) = 1; both are straightforward I guess.

Comment: If $X,Y$ are independent random variables with distribution functions $F,G$, then $FG$ is the distribution function of the random variable $\min(X,Y)$.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland: Nice remark, sidesteps computation. But I think $FG$ is the cdf of $\max(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 7):

If, as the caps hint at, you mean that $F$ and $G$ are *cumulative* distribution functions, the answer is yes. We need to verify that the product has the required properties. So we want to show that $F(x)G(x)$ is continuous from the right, that $\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)G(x)=1$, that $F(x)G(x)$ is non-decreasing, that $\lim_{x\to -\infty} F(x)G(x)=0$. The verifications are straightforward.

Comment: for showing that the product is non-decreasing, do we use the fact that both $F$ and $G$ have codomain $= [0,1]$? because in general the product of non-decreasing functions is not non-decreasing.

Answer (score 6):

If $F$ and $G$ are two distribution functions, the product $FG$ is still a distribution function, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/936079/203369) by André Nicolas. I would like to expand on his comment.

By definition, $F(x) = P(X<x)$, $G(x) = P(Y<x)$ , where $X$ and $Y$ are random variables. Let's prove that, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $P(\max(X,Y)<x) = F(x)G(x)$.

$\max(X,Y) < x  \implies X < x \land Y < x$

$P(\max(X,Y) < x) = P(X < x \land Y < x) = P(X < x)  P( Y<x | X <x)$.

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $P( Y<x | X <x) = P( Y<x)$, and the line above becomes $P(\max(X,Y) < x) = P(X < x)  P( Y<x) =  F(x)G(x)$

If you call $Z=\max(X,Y)$ and the distribution function of Z is $H(x) = P(Z<x) = F(x)G(x)$.