# Convex combination of cumulative distribution functions

Tags: probability

Let $F,G$ be cumulative distributions functions. I need to find a necessary and sufficient condition for $\alpha$ such that $(1-\alpha)F+\alpha G$ is also a cumulative distribution function.

I have found that a sufficient condition is $0 \leq \alpha \leq 1 $, but I'm not sure wether it is a necessity. I'm struggling with proving that given $\alpha >1$ or $\alpha<0$ ,  $(1-\alpha) F+\alpha G$ is not monotonic. 
Any ideas?

Comment: By the way, I think you meant $(1 - \alpha)F + \alpha G$ instead of $(1 - F)\alpha + \alpha G$, based on your comments on my answer. I edited your question, but feel free to roll it back if I'm wrong. (Although, if you *did* mean it the other way, then I think there are no $\alpha$ that work!)

Comment: You are right, It was a mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding the problem correctly and this condition is intended to hold for all $F$ and $G$, then the burden of proof here is pretty straightforward; all you have to do is to furnish a single counterexample (i.e. an $F$ and a $G$ for which the property doesn't hold). But, you can do something even easier: show that if $\alpha > 1$ or $\alpha < 0$, then  $(1-\alpha) F + \alpha G$ can take values below $0$ or above $1$.

A hint for how to proceed: if $X, Y$ are random variables supported on $[2, 3]$ and $[0, 1]$ respectively, with respective CDFs $F$ and $G$, then note that on the interval $(1, 2)$, we must have $F(x) = 0$ and $G(x) = 1$.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I think my problem is with the logic here, if there are indeed two functions $F, G$ and $\alpha > 1$ or $\alpha<0$ such that $(1- \alpha)F + \alpha G$ is a CDF, doesn't it mean that the condition $0 \leq \alpha \leq 1$ is not necessary?

Comment: Not quite. The wording of the question implies that you don't get to pick the $F$ and $G$, but that your condition on $\alpha$ must work for *all* $F$ and $G$. You can think of it like an adversary has chosen an $F$ and $G$ which are unknown to you, and you have to pick an $\alpha$ so that $(1-F)\alpha + \alpha G$ remains a valid distribution no matter what the adversary has chosen. (This is why you can disprove it with just one counterexample in this fashion.)

Comment: Also, let's turn the question on its head; if you can choose *any* $F$ and $G$, then choose the case where $F = G$ and notice that $(1 - \alpha)F + \alpha G = F$ is automatically a valid distribution regardless of what $\alpha$ actually is.

Comment: @Aaron A bit different question. How about $FG$? It's increasing and seems valid. Any corner case?

Comment: @ShivTavker Yes, the pointwise product of two CDFs is a CDF. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936063/product-of-two-distribution-functions

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I could not reach the link through google search.